# restangular - Cannot read property 'all' of undefined

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, restangular

I only have a basic app set up so far so I can try get my head around what data restangular will give me and how. To test, I have a json file available on a local grails install (and I can browse to it at localhost:8080/ewellcheck/questionnaire/active) and I have also duplicated this on the same server as my angular app (localhost:8000/app/testdata.json not sure what the server is - whatever comes with angular seed).

in my app.js I have:

```
.config(function($routeProvider, RestangularProvider) {
  eProvider.when('/dashboard/', {
    templateUrl: 'dashboard.html',
    controller: 'DashboardController'
  });
  RestangularProvider.setBaseUrl('http://localhost:8000/');
})
```

I have also included the restangular dependency where I instantiate my angular app

in controller.js I have:

```
.controller('DashboardController', ['Restangular', function($scope, Restangular) {
  $scope.myData = Restangular.all('app/testdata.json').getList();
}])
```

I have also tried using the grails paths and tried substituting

- Restangular.all with Restangular.one
- getList() with get()

but the result is always the same:

TypeError:  Cannot read property 'all' of undefined.

Guaranteed I'm overlooking something or trying to do something really stupid, but can someone please point out my stupidity for me?

Comment: It should be `['$scope', 'Restangular', function($scope, Restangular)`.. btw it's not that stupid, happens to everyone :)

Comment: thanks @AnthonyChu that's one step closer :) also changed the call to `$scope.myData = Restangular.one('app/testdata.json').get();`
myData is now returning {"restangularCollection":false}...
Any suggestion as to how I actually get the data?

Comment: Try `$scope.myData = Restangular.all('app/testdata.json').getList().$object;`